# How to enable intrinsics in compiler?

Tags: android, c, arm

Who can explain: how to enable intrinsics in c code?

I would like to use [special dsp instructions](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/Cihidceh.html) in armv5TE

Consider `qadd` instruction, it nicely works when i use assembler approach, like this:

```
inline int function_qadd(int a, int b) {
    __asm__ (
            "qadd %0, %1, %2" : "=r" (a) : "r" (a), "r" (b));
    return a;
}
```

But when i tried to use [__qadd intrinsic](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0491c/CJACGAFH.html) instead of asm like this:

```
int add_result = __qadd(5,10);
LOGI("qadd='%d'", add_result);
```

i got error:

> error: undefined reference to '__qadd'

**What i am doing wrong, how to enable intrinsics in c code?**

**UPDATE:**

I have ndk `android-ndk-r8c` (windows version), it [have GCC 4.6 as default](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html):

> The GCC 4.6 compiler is still the default,

Besides i explicitly specify in android.mk

```
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.6
```

My compiler flags is:

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -std=c99 -ffast-math -march=armv5te -mfpu=vfp -mfloat-abi=softfp
```

Besides i check the asm code generated by gcc throught -S compiler flag, it generate qadd instruction:

```
qadd r3, r3, r2
```

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: Every compiler has its own rules for intrinsics. Probably you need to include a header with special declarations.

Comment: Hmm, according to http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0491h/CIHEGGAJ.html the compiler is GCC and the function should not require a declaration. Double check that you're compiling for the right ISA; the assembler might merely be letting you generate instructions for the wrong processor.

Comment: Potatoswatter, that document you linked is documentation for armcc? As far as I am aware, GCC doesn't make __qadd, or any equivalent, available as intrinsics.

Comment: How can i use armcc in compilation?

Comment: try --std=gnu99 also the GCC intrinsics are listed here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-NEON-Intrinsics.html#ARM-NEON-Intrinsics It's likely that the intrinsics are differently named.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intrinsic function __qadd is not available for the GCC compiler. The link to the documentation you've provided is for the (non-free) armcc compiler.

Using the assembler approach is the only practical way to use the qadd instruction if you're using GCC.