# Intrinsic function implementaion on Arm

Tags: c, assembly, arm

I want to optimize a code by using an intrinsic function. Can someone guide for this. Since my code contain MAC (multiplication and addition) statement I suppose to replace with SMLAxy instruction. I tried but getting linking error. I used armintr.h header file but getting:

```
error:armintr.h :No such file or directory
```

I'm using an Intel Ubuntu desktop as a host and my target is an ARM Cortex-a8.  I'm using arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc compiler with `-O3 -mcpu=cortex-a8 -Wall` options flags.

Comment: The error is quite clear. But you have not given any information about which compiler, on what platform etc so that anyone could in any way help you.

Comment: I'm using arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc compiler and arm-cortex-a8

Comment: It looks like `armintr.h` is an MSVC header, not a GCC header.

Comment: Sir, i'm not aware of MSVC...could please guide me

Comment: Michael sir, i want to put intrinsic function on my code how can i proceed? i tried with __smlad(var1,var2,var3) without any header file then getting following error : acelp_ca.c:(.text+0x2e0): undefined reference to `__smlad'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable intrinsics in compiler?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14188262/how-to-enable-intrinsics-in-compiler)

Answer (score 1):

> error:armintr.h :No such file or directory

Usually this error comes when you don't have particular header file in specified path . Or You need to give proper path for this header file.

In your case you have not enabled intrinsic Instruction so you are getting error.

To enable intrinsic specify compiler [option](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489g/Babbidfd.html) e.g. `--fpu=name` .

Comment: --fpu=name replace name with your arch... and have look on link given in ans. If you want really to optimize code go for Neon intrinsic.

Comment: Mohan....just now i came to know that gcc doesn't support intrinsic functions. Is it ture???? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14188262/how-to-enable-intrinsics-in-compiler

Comment: @ChethanShetty that question is about android......I think you need edit your question with detail of Host OS, Target OS, Where you developing your code, if possible post your code or some part of it which cause the problem. and How you decided to use that header file? So people can help you....

Comment: Actually that question somehow related to my problem.I'm using intel desktop as host with ubuntu, and my target is ARM-cortex-a8.                         
#if 1
/*  Intrinsic function  ---- here i'm getting undefined reference to '__smlad error ' */
        cor = __smlad(cor,H[i], H[i]);
#else
    cor = L_mac(cor, H[i], H[i]);
#endif

Comment: Sry for unaligned text.

Comment: Have you tried with flag what he mentioned in that question ...with and without header file ? Still if it is not working go for Neon that will be easy.

Comment: Yes tried with all the flags, again same notification : undefined reference to '__smlad'

Comment: Ya even though i tried with neon -mfpu=neon  and replace with cor = vmlal_s16(cor, H[i], H[i]); getting error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'vmlal_s16'

Comment: Hi mohan here a break through,since i have batch files when i compile those files using make utility getting the error, But when i compilng the single its compiling and __smlad() intrinsic is working how is this possible??  arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-a8 -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp -c  acelp_ca.c -o acelp_ca This producing .obj file without any syntax error and linking error.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect GCC to generate the SMLAL instruction for you without using intrinsics.

```
long long Acc;
long a;
long b;

Acc += ((long long)a*b);
```

Does that not generate the instruction for you.

Comment: Mr.colin, i'm optimizing a code i suppose to use assembly instruction

Comment: Indeed, GCC usually generates `SMULL`/`SMLAL`/etc. just fine. The question _seems_ to be asking about `SMLABB`/`SMLABT`/`SMLATB`/`SMLATT`, though, which the GCC 4.8 I tried doesn't seem to have an optimisation for (although [apparently Clang does](https://goo.gl/SrQ60y)).

Comment: @Notlikethat I do seem to remember gcc emitting these in some circumstances.  It is often difficult to get a compiler to do this because of pendantic mappings in 'C' for overflow and other cirumstances.  Probably at least `-ffast-math` is helpful/needed?  At least is in the [arm.md](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=gcc/config/arm/arm.md;h=5782b357aa2c3e02b1aecf93576cd6561d7d08d8;hb=HEAD#l1780) so it should be emitted in some circumstances.

Comment: @artlessnoise Ah, it just doesn't like them in Thumb - [it does emit them with `-marm`](https://goo.gl/rZ2gZM).